# Using full CPU to bake mantaflow simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking

I have dual 8-core Xeon e5-2780 0 (2.7ghz) processors, and 128gb of RAM. When trying to bake mantaflow fluid simulations, even the simplest simulations take forever because usually it is only using a small percentage of my CPUs. When trying to bake at 300 quality for instance, it uses 10-20%, and takes hours to bake a small animation. Is this a problem with server cpus? They do not combine cpu core strength easily? Or is there a way to implement using all threads on baking fluid in mantaflow. Any help appreciated.

Also, when baking at 64 quality (extremely low) simulations take 15 minutes.

Comment: Can you use top or a similar system monitoring tool to see if it's multithreading? If it's not, there's probably not much you can do, server chips like your xeon really only care about multi core performance. 2.7 GHz is pretty slow by today's standardrs.

Comment: It may be multi-threading, however it is using the smallest amount of cpu. It appears that server cpus dedicate the most cpu to the most intensive tasks. That is what I want to fix. For instance: rendering is lightning fast, and takes only a couple minutes for a complex scene because it is using 100% cpu.

Comment: Does this mean that it is multithreading? Use a system monitor and see if it's actually using all 16 of your cores. If your CPU load is low and it is multithreading (check this, it matters far more than overall usage), that points to a bottleneck elsewhere in the system. From the little I know about mantaflow, that would probably be a RAM bottleneck, which seems unlikely if you've got 128 GBs. If your CPU load is low and it's not multithreading, this is probably just your CPU. Monitor your clock speeds to see if it's throttling.

Comment: Thank you. I will see if this fixes my issue.

Comment: I found the problem: I have a SheepIt renderfarm client running in the background. It was using a lot of RAM and also a lot of CPU